Row count in a SAS file using R's haven package or others
I have a large SAS file to read on a smaller memory machine. I know how to use skip and n_max in combination in a read_sas call using haven package to actually read the file in chunks and process. However, I am wondering if there is a way to get the row count and even the list of columns in the SAS file before reading it in.
In python, this works (Read SAS file to get meta information):
import pyreadstat

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat('sasFile.sas7bdat', metadataonly=True)
meta.number_rows

Need equivalent in R.

What type of "SAS file" do you have? Is it a SAS dataset? A transport file?

sas7bdat as shown in the example.

For the column names: nms <- names(read_sas("filename", n_max=0))

For the rows: rows <- nrow(read_sas("filename", col_select=nms[1])). Both of these involve partially reading in the data.

Yeah, I am aware of the obvious answer like this one. :) Looking for the above python equivalent, if it exists in a package I am unaware of.
